# Passing QuerySnapshot data to a list and accessing data within the list

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have a query, and I'd like to use a for loop to populate a list with the data held in each document for a particular field.

I'd like to process the data after, and it's easier doing this to a list rather than a Querysnapshot

My code is as follows:

```
return FutureBuilder(
      future: _fetchedLatestMood,
      builder: (BuildContext context,
          AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          //set noDocs == returned length from firestore
          noDocs = snapshot.data!.docs.length;

          for (int i = 0; i < noDocs; i++) {
            moodReturn[i] = (snapshot.data!.docs[i].data()!["actual"]).toString();
          }
```

If I call `${snapshot.data!.docs[i].data()!["actual"])}` within the text widget, I get the expected data I am looking, so I am confident the future is building and data is available.

Currently, nothing will render on the screen when I call the for loop, not getting any errors as I'm building in release mode (only way I can get Xcode to build after update)

Anyone any ideas, have I missed a concept I should know?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to use  moodReturn.add()

I had defined a list of no size as I wanted it to be growable, I was trying to access an index that didn't exist

```
 for (int i = 0; i < noDocs; i++) {
            moodReturn.add( (snapshot.data!.docs[i].data()!["actual"]).toString());
          }
```